# How to check if a type is marked with an attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, attributes

Does it needs reflection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
Attribute.IsDefined(yourType, attributeType);
```

Except for `[Serializable]`, which might *also* be `yourType.IsSerializable` (if you check the IL, `[Serializable]` **doesn't** *actually* get written as an attribute - there is a special type modifier; either approach works fine, though).